# How to use requests to download files with original names?

Tags: python, python-requests

I made a little script to automate some downloads, but I have a little issue. For example, the link is **www.link.com/29292292.pdf** but If I press the download button in my browser the name of the file is **file with a good name.pdf**.

I don't know to tell to requests to download the file but with 'file with a good name.pdf'.

Comment: Can you see in the HTML of that website if the link to the file is different than the title? Do you have an example download?

Comment: The filename may be available to you in one of the response headers (in particular the `content-type` header).

Comment: The page of where I scrap the downloads links is [this](http://link.springer.com/openurl?genre=book&isbn=978-0-306-48048-5) and a direct download links is [this](http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-319-12493-3.pdf)

Comment: Oh, let me check about ```content-type```. Do you have an example?

Comment: I fixed it (well something like that), thank you for the ```content-type``` help :).